# Can't bind to property 'satPopoverAnchorFor' with the component @ncstate/sat-popover

Tags: angular, angular-material, popover

Sorry for this basic question. I'm new with Angular project.

I would like to use the component @ncstate/sat-popover with an Angular material table. The purpose is to get inline editing of fields in the rows of my table. I get my inspiration from this example from stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/inline-edit-mat-table?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Example of the way i've used it:

```html
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [satPopoverAnchorFor]="p" (click)="p.open()">
      <ng-container *ngIf="row.consumption_id">
        {{row.consumption_id}}
      </ng-container>

      <span class="add-consumption_id" *ngIf="!row.consumption_id">
        Add a consumption id.
      </span>

      <sat-popover #p
          hasBackdrop
          xAlign="start"
          yAlign="start"
          (closed)="update(row, $event)">
        <inline-edit [value]="row.consumption_id"></inline-edit>
      </sat-popover>
    </mat-cell>
```

I get the error:

```js
SCRIPT5022: Template parse errors:
**Can't bind to 'satPopoverAnchorFor' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-cell'.**
1. If 'mat-cell' is an Angular component and it has 'satPopoverAnchorFor' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
...
```

I've recreated 2 times this project with different version of Angular (8.0.0 and 8.1.0)

Everything looks correctly installed and imported in my project.

Any idea of what i've missed?

Thank you,
Fred

Answer (score 12):

In the latest release the attribute changed from [satPopoverAnchorFor] to [satPopoverAnchor].

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let product" [satPopoverAnchor]="p" (click)="p.open()">  {{product.case_height}}
        <sat-popover #p
        hasBackdrop
        xAlign="start"
        yAlign="start"
        (closed)="updateProduct(product,'case_height', $event)">

               <inline-edit [sku]="product.case_height" [fieldname]="'Case Height'" [fieldvalue]="product.case_height"></inline-edit>
        </sat-popover>


 </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `<mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" satPopoverAnchorFor="p" (click)="p.open()">`

Comment: I've removed the brackets and now i get the same error on the tag inline-edit.  SCRIPT5022: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'inline-edit'. Thus, i 've removed the brackets on the property value also and the result is : SCRIPT5022: Template parse errors:
'inline-edit' is not a known element.

Comment: This doesn't work - it won't find the attribute when you click on it